# How to know Gcm Message is Received By recipient?

Tags: android

I am New in android and i am working with **GCM** in android .I want to get the status of message that is delivered or not.

My code is shown below.

```
  private void sendMessage(List<SearchChildrenInformationData> searchedChildrensList) {
            {
                try {
                    Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
                    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(50)
                            .delayWhileIdle(false).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, senderMessage)
                            .build();

                    for (int i = 0; i <= searchedChildrensList.size() - 1; i++) {
                        String regid = searchedChildrensList.get(i).getSchoolId();
                        Result multiResult = sender
                                .send(message, regid, 1);
                        System.out.println("#####REsult++++" + multiResult);

                    }
                    searchedChildrensList.clear();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

`
```